# Asp.net core why the source code is converted to assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

i want to understand something   , if asp.net core is an open source framework 
why  i can't read the definition of the functions and the source code on visual studio  and it's compiled to assembly , why it's not just a project and we can see all the code and understand what going behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the fact that .NET Core is fully open sourced does nothing to do with the other fact that C# is compiled into [*Common Intermediate Language* (CIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and executed by the *Core Common Language Runtime* (CoreCLR).

That is, C# is a *compiled language*. With .NET Native, C# is also compiled into machine code (assembler) instead of *intermediate language*.

In other words, you don't execute source code with your programs in .NET like an interpreted language.

### You can still achieve your goal...

Since ASP.NET Core and .NET Core are open source products, if you compile them yourself in your own machine and you add project references to them in your solution, you'll get what you want.

BTW, you'll end up building the entire ASP.NET Core and .NET Core as part of your own solution.....

Comment: Or you can just download the projects and add the references... Pretty easy task

Comment: thank you for ur answer it was very helpful , so if i can download the projects and add the references why they didn't do so   which will give us the chance to see what goes behind the scene , or the CIL has other purposes ?